# Log 403(Forbidden) at service side

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to log 403 Forbidden requests to my database using Nlog
this is what I tried so far

In the Configure method, this is what I wrote

Controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = Role.User)]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
```

Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
    {
     builder.Run(async context =>
                {
                    ...
                });
            });

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
            {
                var userId = LocalSecurityHelper.GetUserId(context.User);
                if (userId > 0)
                {
                    logger.LogWarning(userId, "Unauthorized Request");
                }
                else
                {
                    logger.LogWarning("Unauthorized Request");
                }
            }

            await next();
        });

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
```

I intentionally logged in with different role and trying to hit Actions Methods in Users Controller that obviously giving me 403 forbidden but I also want to log that in my database.

edit: updated the code

Comment: ASP.NET Core middlewares run in a very specific order. Just knowing that you inject a middleware is the same as not knowing anything without knowing when exactly it is being injected.

Comment: You most likely need this to run *after* `app.UseAuthentication();` but *before* `app.UseAuthorization();`

Comment: I'm new to .net core, thanks for the info, I'll go through the middleware.
so I moved my code in between Authentication Authorization, this time my response status code is 200 :|

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [mre]? The current code doesn't modify the response so it shouldn't be the cause

Comment: thanks for the reply, I've updated the code, hope this gives what I was trying

Comment: I solved this issue by moving my code about Authentication & authorization